# Class Library (.Net Framework) not supporting Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have created a Class Project (Class Library) for Login. I have installed EF >> created models >> Created Data Context file >> Executed "enable-migration" command in NuGet Package Manager >> Executed "add-migration" command in NuGet Package Manager.
Now when I was trying to executed last step - "update-database" command in NuGet Package Manager, it threw an error **"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)"**. There is no issue with connection because I repeated the same steps, but this time I used Web Project. It worked **successfully**.

**Reason why was I doing this:** I have 3 different application which uses same user authentication. I thought I can refer this class project in all 3 projects for authentication.

Am I doing something wrong? What am I missing? Or is it that Class project doesn't support EF? Is there any work around?

**Edit:** Class Library uses App.Config and Web Application uses Web.config.

*Thank you in advance.*

PS: <strike>Warning</strike> *Advice* for auditors - I just need answers. Please don't try to tell me that this question is duplicate, not following rules, etc. because I don't care. Let me get answer then you may block my question all you want. Till then have patients and sit quietly without making any comments.

Comment: The error says that it is not able to connect to sql server. It has nothing to do with EF or class library. Check your connection string. Try to connect to the server from sql management studio from the machine where you are writing code.

Comment: "Warning for auditors [...]" -- that's not how this site works.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Connection String was same in both Class Library and Web Application. I copied it so there is no mistake of mistyping.

Comment: Forgot to mention - Class Library is using App.config and Web Application uses Web.config. Can that be the reason that it's not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found solution to this.
When I install Entity Framework, EF places some default code in application's config file. As below:

**Problem Code:**

```
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
    <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
    </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
```

**Solution:**

This was root of the problem I was facing. By default it was creating a local connection string for itself. I made following changes:

```
1.) Changed "LocalDbConnectionFactory" to "SqlConnectionFactory"
2.) Removed parameters tag completely.
```

So it should look like this:

```
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
```